# Best way to fix dns redirect issue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I've purchased a domain from amazon and I want to redirect [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to domain.com.

Additional context:

I've created 2 s3 buckets:

1. domain.com which has static webhosting, public access policy and a root index.html
2. [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) that has static webhosting with a redirect to domain.com

I've created a cloudfront distribution with a ssl cert that accepts *.domain.com and origins for both buckets.

I've created route53 entries for domain.com and [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) that has the standard ns, soa, an A record pointing to the cloudfront distribution.

What I've tried:

- using the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) bucket url -> works!
- navigating to domain.com -> works!
- using the cloudfront distribution -> works!
- using the domain.com bucket url -> works!

but using [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) fails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake here is that I had used [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) as a separate hosted zone. Instead there should only be one hosted zone - domain.com and [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) should be an A record that points to the cloudfront distribution in which the distribution lists [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) as an alternate domain name.